# C# - Detect when string is beyond [MaxLength(#)] and truncate?

Tags: c#, truncate, maxlength

I have a object class like so:

```
public class MyObject
{
   [MaxLength(128)]
   public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

However, when I make MyObject with a string for Name of more than 128 characters, I can set it and it works. This causes issues down the line because when I go to insert this object into the database, it exceptions due to the string being to long for that column in the table.

How would I go about making sure that a string that is too long gets truncated? And how can I detect when that happens so I can log it?

Comment: I feel like that attribute only limits it for database storage. As in, the database value can only hold 128. It doesn't restrict the string length itself

Comment: Can you just truncate it on the save or whatever action you are doing

Comment: Where does the MaxLength attribute come from? Can you post a full name (with namespace) to better understand the context?

Comment: An attribute, all by itself, will really do nothing. There must be code that reads them and acts upon its data. Have you wrote code checking for the length? Or using a library or something that uses such attributes?

Comment: Ideally you shouldn't necessarily need to validate the data model. You should guarantee that the input to the data model is valid before you even build the object. Your API model, for example, should be validated properly.

Answer (score 5):

In the setter you can add some validation.

```
public class MyObject
{
    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) || value.Length <= 128)
            {
                name = value;
            }
            else
            {
                //log? do something or truncate
                name = value.Substring(0, 127);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively I don't like it but I tried to make it work with an Attribute and made it easier to scale with a helper class.

```
public class MyObject
{
    private string name;
    [MaxLength(128, ErrorMessage = "String is longer than {1} characters and has been truncated.")]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            name = value.Validate(GetType().GetProperty(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name.Substring(4)).GetCustomAttributes(false));
        }
    }
}

public static class Tools
{
    public static string Validate(this string value, object[] attributes)
    {
        if (attributes.FirstOrDefault(x => x is MaxLengthAttribute) is MaxLengthAttribute maxLengthAttribute)
        {
            if (maxLengthAttribute.IsValid(value))
            {
                return value;
            }
            else
            {
                //LogMethod(maxLengthAttribute.FormatErrorMessage(maxLengthAttribute.MaximumLength.ToString()));
                return value.Substring(0, maxLengthAttribute.Length - 1);
            }
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't want to hardcode this like that for every property now do you?

Comment: @CodeCaster I tried to make it easier to reuse across multiple properties, there might be a better way to do this though.

Comment: There is. You don't want to add this to every property, it makes for unreadable and unmaintainable code. Just add the attribute, and have another layer of the application validate them.